# How can I use "Linq to Objects" to put a set of contiguous dates in one group?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a troublesome query to write. I'm currently writing some nasty for loops to solve it, but I'm curious to know if Linq can do it for me.

I have:

```
struct TheStruct
{
 public DateTime date {get; set;} //(time portion will always be 12 am)
 public decimal A {get; set;}
 public decimal B {get; set;}
}
```

and a list that contains these structs. Let's say it's ordered this way:

```
List<TheStruct> orderedList = unorderedList.OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList();
```

If you put the orderedList struct dates in a set they will always be contiguous with respect to the day.. that is if the latest date in the list was 2011/01/31, and the earliest date in the list was 2011/01/01, then you'd find that the list would contain 31 items, one for each date in January.

Ok, so what I want to do is group the list items such that:

1. Each item in a group must contain the same Decimal A value and the same Decimal B value
2. The date values in a group must form a set of contiguous dates, if the date values were in order
3. If you summed up the sums of items in each group, the total would equal the number of items in the original list (or you could say a struct with a particular date can't belong to more than one group)

Any Linq masters know how to do this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you had values (1,1) for Dec 1st - Dec 10th, values (1,2) for Dec 11th - Dec 20th, and values (1,1) for Dec 21st - Dec 31st, would you want two groups of output or three?  If two, would you want a gap in the (1,1) dates or some default values of A and B for the missing dates?

Comment: I want three groups. If there were a gap then you could not form the set of continuous dates. If I filled A and B with default values in the gap then I'd have more items in all the groups than I originally started with

Comment: So you want to `GroupBy` `A` *and* `B`.  Then within each group `OrderBy` `date`?  Or do you need them to be `Distinct` too?

Comment: I need to group by A and B, but the hard part is how do I also tell Linq that the dates in the returned group must be continuous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group adjacent items in a sequence using the [GroupAdjacent Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364977/76217) (see below):

```
var result = unorderedList
    .OrderBy(x => x.date)
    .GroupAdjacent((g, x) => x.A == g.Last().A && 
                             x.B == g.Last().B && 
                             x.date == g.Last().date.AddDays(1))
    .ToList();
```

*Example:*

```
(1,1) 2011-01-01   \
(1,1) 2011-01-02    >  Group 1
(1,1) 2011-01-03 __/
(2,1) 2011-01-04   \
(2,1) 2011-01-05    >  Group 2
(2,1) 2011-01-06 __/
(1,1) 2011-01-07   \
(1,1) 2011-01-08    >  Group 3
(1,1) 2011-01-09 __/
(1,1) 2011-02-01   \
(1,1) 2011-02-02    >  Group 4
(1,1) 2011-02-03 __/
```

*Extension Method:*

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacent<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool> adjacent)
{
    var g = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (g.Count != 0 && !adjacent(g, x))
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<T>();
        }
        g.Add(x);
    }
    yield return g;
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. What I didn't know is how to group 'adjacent' Dates. I'll try it out!

Comment: This will work, but I think it could be rather inefficient because of the use of IEnumerable in the `adjacent` function.  If I'm not mistaken, that's going to cause repeated list iteration with those .Last() calls, which will be something like 2N! iterations if all of your items had the same A and B.

Comment: With that said, it's about 50x more elegant than my solution :-)

Comment: @ChrisShain: If I'm not mistaken, the Last() method is quite clever and checks if the enumerable is an IList<T>. If it is, it uses `source[source.Count - 1]` to get the last item instead of iterating the whole sequence.

Comment: Just checked in reflector- you are absolutely correct.  I retract my earlier comment :-)

Comment: Hey thanks, this works well. And you forced me to learn how to make an extension method too!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an entry for "Most Convoluted way to do this":

```
public static class StructOrganizer
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<Decimal, Decimal, IEnumerable<MyStruct>>> OrganizeWithoutGaps(this IEnumerable<MyStruct> someStructs)
    {
        var someStructsAsList = someStructs.ToList();
        var lastValuesSeen = new Tuple<Decimal, Decimal>(someStructsAsList[0].A, someStructsAsList[0].B);
        var currentList = new List<MyStruct>();
        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, someStructsAsList.Count)
            .ToList()
            .Select(i =>
                        {
                            var current = someStructsAsList[i];
                            if (lastValuesSeen.Equals(new Tuple<Decimal, Decimal>(current.A, current.B)))
                                currentList.Add(current);
                            else
                            {
                                lastValuesSeen = new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(current.A, current.B);
                                var oldList = currentList;
                                currentList = new List<MyStruct>(new [] { current });
                                return new Tuple<decimal, decimal, IEnumerable<MyStruct>>(lastValuesSeen.Item1, lastValuesSeen.Item2, oldList);
                            }
                            return null;
                        })
            .Where(i => i != null);
    }

    // To Test:
    public static void Test()
    {
        var r = new Random();

        var sampleData = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new MyStruct {A = r.Next(0, 2), B = r.Next(0, 2), date = new DateTime(2011, 12, i)}).OrderBy(s => s.date).ToList();
        var sortedData = sampleData.OrganizeWithoutGaps();

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Sample Data:");
        sampleData.ForEach(s => Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} = ({1}, {2})", s.date, s.A, s.B));
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Output:");
        sortedData.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.Out.WriteLine("({0}, {1}) = {2}", s.Item1, s.Item2, String.Join(", ", s.Item3.Select(st => st.date))));
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure came up with that one in a hurry!

Comment: @IBC the joys of Resharper and TestDriven.net...  Besides, was working on it from when I wrote my comment, so maybe 10 min to write.

Comment: 349 for resharper... Would you say it's worth it?

Comment: Worth every penny.  Once you use it, you'll never go back.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, a simple Group By would do the trick:

```
var orderedList = unorderedList.OrderBy(o => o.date).GroupBy(s => new {s.A, s.B});
```

Just that. To print the results:

```
      foreach (var o in orderedList) {                 
            Console.WriteLine("Dates of group {0},{1}:", o.Key.A, o.Key.B);
            foreach(var s in o){
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", s.date);
            }
        }
```

The output would be like:

```
Dates of group 2,3:
    02/12/2011
    03/12/2011
Dates of group 4,3:
    03/12/2011
Dates of group 1,2:
    04/12/2011
    05/12/2011
    06/12/2011
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Will this return two group 1,2 if 1,2 occurred in day 1, 2, and 3 and also day 6, 7 and 9?

Comment: This won't work, it only groups by the numbers regardless of what the date is.

Comment: Yes, it groups by numbers. I didn't understand your requirements well.