# Splitting List Of Strings Based on Numbering

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have several numbered lists stored in a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> all = new List<string>()
{
  "1. Apple",
  "2. Banana",
  "3. Coconut",
  "1. Ant",
  "2. Beaver",
  "3. Cat"
  ...
}
```

I want to split this list into a list of lists where each list contains 1-3.

```
List<List<string>> split = new List<List<string>>()
{
  new List<string>() { "1. Apple", "2. Banana", "3. Coconut"},
  new List<string>() { "1. Ant", "2. Beaver", "3. Cat"}
}
```

There will ALWAYS be "1." so I can use that as my delimiter.  Is there a slick way to do this with LINQ without needing two nested for loops?

Update: I'd like this to be generalized for any length, not always 3.

Comment: Is there any guarantee to the order or number of items in each group?

Comment: "1." will always be present and denotes the start of a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option to get desired result (assign group index to each item in sequence, then group by that index):

```
int groupIndex = 0;
List<List<string>> split = all.Select(s => {
                                   if (s.StartsWith("1."))
                                      groupIndex++;
                                   return new { groupIndex, s }; })
                              .GroupBy(x => x.groupIndex)
                              .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.s).ToList())
                              .ToList();
```

---

Another option - accumulate results (this will require one traverse over the list)

```
List<List<string>> split =
    all.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(), (acc, s) =>
                    { 
                        if (s.StartsWith("1."))
                            acc.Add(new List<string>());
                        acc[acc.Count - 1].Add(s);
                        return acc; 
                    });
```

Comment: This was essentially what I was trying to do. I new thought about declaring a temp groupIndex to help. Out of pure curiosity, is there a way to have groupIndex somehow only be local to the linq query.

Comment: @Mark I don't think it's easy to use local groupIndex, but you can use aggregation (updated sample)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use the dictionary type instead. Rather than storing the number of the item and the item itself, you can set the item number as the key and the item itself as the value. Here is an example of how you might accomplish that:

```
newList = {'1':'Apple','2':'Banana','3':'Pear'}  
animalList = {'1':'Bear','2':'Cat','3':'Dog'}
```

You can iterate through each item, or use a method to call by keys or values.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was submitting just as the first answer got posted. Correct!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> result = all.GroupAdjacent((g, x) => !x.StartsWith("1."))
                               .Select(g => g.ToList())
                               .ToList();
```

using the *GroupAdjacent Extension Method* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364977/76217).

Comment: +1 But I think copy-pasting extension method here will be nice

Comment: I like the extension method, but I think you need to better educate the OP on what you are doing, give him an explanation of the *why* and *how*.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a *slick* way of doing this using LINQ without making a bunch of assumptions about the list, and the only guaranteed bit of information that you've given us is *"there will always be a 1."*. Will there always be groups of 3 items, or will there sometimes be more or less?

Why not change the way the strings are stored to begin with - use a `List<List<string>>` instead, so you have a `List` of `List<string>`?